# iOS UILabel autoresize text to frame no matter the font

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, font-size

I have a unusual thing that I need to accomplish but don't know how.

I have a UILabel and want to set it to a specific height and then size the text inside it so the first char is equal to that specific height and the rest just get the calculated font size.

I have tried to use `myLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;` but it does not really solve my problem because it uses the greates character in the text and it still adds the vertical padding/spacing that a font might have.

The image should describe what I want to accomplish. You can see that the height should be 200px and that the first character is exactly 200px without any padding/spacing added vertically.

Anyone have any idea of how to solve this?

Thanks in advance
Vatan
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution based on rendering an image where the label is displayed with a font-size we can get where the character starts and where it ends. With this we can determine the height of the current char in pixels. Next part is to give the label a new font-size and then repeat the previous step by rendering an image. This will give same size of the character no matter the font.

To use it you need to add the following code to your controller and then just call the method `setSizeFont (sizeFont: CGFloat, center:CGPoint)` where the sizeFont is the desired size for the character and center is where to place the label (I needed this parameter in my program, it may not be useful to others)

If the solution can be improved please feel free to edit

```
extension UIImage {
    func getPixelColor(pos: CGPoint) -> UIColor {

        var pixelData = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(self.CGImage))
        var data: UnsafePointer<UInt8> = CFDataGetBytePtr(pixelData)

        var pixelInfo: Int = ((Int(self.size.width) * Int(pos.y)) + Int(pos.x)) * 4

        var r = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo]) / CGFloat(255.0)
        var g = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo+1]) / CGFloat(255.0)
        var b = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo+2]) / CGFloat(255.0)
        var a = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo+3]) / CGFloat(255.0)

        return UIColor(red: r, green: g, blue: b, alpha: a)
    }

    private func getHeight() -> Int {
        var startHeight = 0
        var endHeight = Int(round(self.size.height))
        outerLoop: for var index = 0; index < Int(round(self.size.height)); index++ {
            for var j = 0; j < Int(round(self.size.width)); j++ {
                if(self.getPixelColor(CGPoint(x:j, y:index)) == UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)) {
                    startHeight = index
                    break outerLoop
                }
            }
        }

        outerLoop: for var index = Int(round(self.size.height))-1; index >= 0; index -= 1 {
            for var j = 0; j < Int(round(self.size.width)); j++ {
                if(self.getPixelColor(CGPoint(x:j, y:index)) == UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)) {
                    endHeight = index

                    break outerLoop
                }
            }
        }

        return endHeight-startHeight
    }
}

extension UILabel {
    func setSizeFont (sizeFont: CGFloat, center:CGPoint) {

        var str = self.text!
        str = str.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())

        var tempLabel = UILabel(frame: self.frame)
        //Set text to only be the first char
        tempLabel.text = str.substringWithRange(Range<String.Index>(start: advance(str.startIndex, 0), end: advance(str.startIndex, 1)))
        tempLabel.font = UIFont(name: self.font.fontName, size: sizeFont)!
        tempLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        tempLabel.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        tempLabel.sizeToFit()


        self.font =  UIFont(name: self.font.fontName, size: sizeFont)!


        var height = tempLabel.generateImg().getHeight()
        var sizeF = Int(round(sizeFont))
        var currSize = sizeF

        while( height < sizeF ) {
            var diff = sizeF - height
            if(diff<=5){
                currSize++
            } else {
                currSize += diff-5
            }
            tempLabel.font = UIFont(name: tempLabel.font.fontName, size: CGFloat(currSize))!
            tempLabel.sizeToFit()
            height = tempLabel.generateImg().getHeight()
        }

        self.font = UIFont(name: self.font.fontName, size: CGFloat(currSize))

        self.sizeToFit()

        self.center = center

    }
    private func generateImg() -> UIImage{

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.bounds.size);

        // Make the CALayer to draw in our "canvas".
        self.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())

        // Fetch an UIImage of our "canvas".
        var image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

        // Stop the "canvas" from accepting any input.
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        return image
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the height of the UILabel to always match the height of the first character, you can use `sizeToFit` but don't include the entire string, just the first character. Then, after the UILabel's frame is already calculated, based on the first letter alone, you can add the rest of your text, and the label will still be in the required height.

I hope this helps. Good luck!

**EDIT:** You can get the exact height for the character you need based on these UIFont characteristics. The image explains it very well. You may need a slightly different calculation based on the character you're currently dealing with, but, as you can see in the image, you have all of the necessary data for the calculation: [A great visualization of UIFont properties](https://i1.wp.com/www.cocoanetics.com/files/Screen-shot-2010-02-09-at-7.03.33-PM.png)

Comment: If I set the font to be 200px the char will not be exactly 200px since it will have some spacing at the top and bottom, this spacing I need to remove before i use sizeToFit

Comment: Checkout the link I added to the original answer. I hope it will give you everything you need to resolve the issue.

Comment: Thanks, I will check it out and come back to you later on

Comment: Hi, I'm stuck at trying to find out which value I should use for the first character. Is it possible to find out if a char has an ascender, descender etc?

Comment: I think you should base it on the specific character used as the first one. The calculation will be different in cases where the first character is 'x' than in cases where the first character is 'p'. For example, if the character is 'a', the height you're looking for will simply be xHeight. But, if the character is 'k', the height will be capHeight. And for 'q', you'll use xHeight-descender. I hope this helps...

Comment: yes, does it not exist any function that will tell me if this character has a descender or something because otherwise I need to write a huge table to cover all the alphabets.

Comment: I'm not aware of such a method. However, it won't be such a huge table. You can simply have one case for capital letters, another for (b,d,f,h,k,l,t), another for (g,j,p,q) and then all the rest. Four separate treatments (even though technically you can combine the treatment for the capital letters and the ones with the ascender to the same condition and be left with only three options.

Comment: A problem I encountered is that almost all fonts uses Cap height for numbers but some fonts uses xHeight and for special chars like äåö the fonts handle them completely different, you can see how the table and the different cases are growing :) 
Is it possible to somehow use the graphical objects to inspect every pixel in the label (after it has been rendered) and determine how big the character is and then keep doing this until the correct size?

Comment: I guess you can take a snapshot of the view and examine the black vs white/transparent pixels in each of the columns, but that seems like something that will be very expensive (time/resource wise) to run, and probably almost irrelevant for real-time use... :-/

Comment: I have added a solution based on examining the black vs white. Do you think it can be improved significally?

Answer (score 0):

```
[labelAutoResizeCheck setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:labelAutoResizeCheck.font.fontName size:90]];
```

after setting font, Do this..

```
CGSize sizeAsPerText = [labelAutoResizeCheck.text sizeWithFont:labelAutoResizeCheck.font];
[labelAutoResizeCheck setFrame:CGRectMake(labelAutoResizeCheck.frame.origin.x, labelAutoResizeCheck.frame.origin.y, sizeAsPerText.width, sizeAsPerText.height)];
```

Comment: hi, how would I write this with swift and in xcode 6 since some of the functions doesn't exist?

Comment: @VatanBytyqi on my Xcode 6.4, for swift, after setting text and font to a label, i just do label.sizeToFit() . its works well

Comment: If you check it in more detail you will see that the char is not exactly the prefered size, because fonts have some spacing for different type och chars.